# How to fetch range based on number in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with two columns. One is start and another column is end.
If I give any number it has to pick all matching rows in the table.
Example:

```
start |  End
100   |  200
100   |  500
1     |  345
200   |  400
```

If i give 123 it should pick:

```
100 | 200
100 | 500
1   | 345
```

How to write query for this?

Comment: I have removed the MySQL tag, as you state this is an Oracle question.

Answer (score 2):

Inclusive select:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE @value BETWEEN start AND end
```

Exclusive select:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE @value > start AND value < end
```

Comment: But I dont have start and end. I have only number.

Comment: How should I understand this: "I have table with two columns. One is start and another column is end."

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your confusion with this task:

```
with t(strt, En) as (
  select 100,  200 from dual union all
  select 100,  500 from dual union all
  select 1,  345 from dual union all
  select 200,  400 from dual
)
select *
  from t
 where 123 between strt and en

STRT     EN
-----------
 100    200
 100    500
   1    345
```